# how can i convert this array into that (below mentioned) and by making another sub array into it in typescript

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, typescript

```
[{
     "header": "API",
     "value": "hello"
  },
  {
     "header":"API",
     "value":"yellow"
 },
   {
     "header":"Other",
      "value":"yallow"},
    {
      "header":"other",
      "value":"othertt"
     }

   ]
```

This is the list i have and i want to change in onto this by match whose header is same lie under one object and other values come in array e.g in the case of "API" header of the object is API and get all values of header into an array and put all values who have header match with "api" make array of them and put them into that object all i want that is one header with array of values below is the output what i want to make from this object array. How is this possible in typescript

```
 [
   {
     "header": "API",
     "data": [
     {
         "value": "hello"
     },
     { 
         "value": "yellow"
      },
     ]

   },

  {
    "header": "other",
    "data": [
    {
         "value": "yallow"
    }
   { 
         "value": "othertt"
   }


   ]}
  ]
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: what you mean ?? i cant got you what are you trying to say @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is proved to work in my test angular app:

```js
const arr = [{
      "header": "API",
      "value": "hello"
    },
    {
      "header":"API",
      "value":"yellow"
    },
    {
      "header":"other",
      "value":"yallow"
    },
    {
      "header":"other",
      "value":"othertt"
    }];
    
    const keys = [];

    for (let i of arr) {
      if (!keys.includes(i.header)) keys.push(i.header);
    }

    const result = keys
      .map(k => Object.assign({ header: k }, { 
        data: arr.filter(x => x.header === k)
        .map(y => Object.assign({}, { value: y.value })) 
      }));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Comment: i need solution in typescript

Comment: Well, I successfully executed this code inside a component method in a regular angular app setup with angular-cli.

Comment: in angular 2 ?? and is this code given the output same like the object below that i have mention in my comment ?

Comment: angular 4. whatever, the thing is typescript rules are passed. the code logs your final object `result` into console. it's up to you what you do with it further.